# When are continuous-time models important?

Tags: finance, random-walk, brownian-motion, discrete-time, continuous-time

In Econometrics, majority of the models are in discrete-time setting, whereas when you move on to quantitative finance, continuous-time models are most prevalent. I get the theory and idea behind continuous time models: take a random walk model - i.e. $Y_t=Y_{t-1}+u_t$, divide $t$ into $n$ increments and as the intervals between two time-stamps converge to zero, then you would end up with a Wiener process (apologies for the crude and mathematically abusive definition, but you get the idea). Same goes with the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and its discrete-time counterpart, the AR(1) process.

Of course, these definitions suggest the ability to capture minute changes in the process. However, in finance I notice these continuous models are often estimated/calibrated at times using daily frequency or even monthly frequency data. What benefit do these bring that an analogous discrete model cannot bring?

Comment: They are convenient analytically, i.e. for deriving various results and properties.